# vb- multidimensional array to one dimension array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I define a two dimension array and one dimension array:

```
    Dim A2(,) As Decimal = New Decimal(1, 2) {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
    Dim A1(2) As Decimal
```

now I want to set the value of A1 to the value of A2(0)- which is also an array of 2 (actually 3) Decimal.

```
    A1= A2(0) ' To insert {1,2,3} to A1
```

How can I write this in vb??

I'll metion That I can't use List, my code must use this simple arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code the answer is: `It can't be done`. The array `A1` can only hold decimal values and not an array of decimal values.

```
A1(0) = 123D ' Can hold a decimal value, not an array of decimals.
A1(1) = 345D ' Can hold a decimal value, not an array of decimals.
A1(2) = 854D ' Can hold a decimal value, not an array of decimals.
```

For this to work, the array `A1` must be declared as an array of arrays:

```
Dim A1 As Decimal()() = New Decimal(2)() {}
```

Now you can assign arrays to `A1`:

```
A1(0) = {1D, 2D, 3D}
```

**Example**

```
Dim A2 As Decimal(,) = New Decimal((2 - 1), (3 - 1)) {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
Dim A1 As Decimal()() = New Decimal(2 - 1)() {}

For i As Integer = 0 To (2 - 1)
    Dim array As Decimal() = New Decimal(3 - 1) {}
    For j As Integer = 0 To (3 - 1)
        array(j) = A2(i, j)
    Next
    A1(i) = array
Next

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (From a As Decimal() In A1 Select String.Join(",", a)).ToArray()))
```

Output:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: OK, but I want to insert A2(0,*) value- How to write that?? A2(0)() or A2(0,*) doesn't pass compilation- what is the syntax?

Comment: You'll have to loop through the desired rank and build the array yourself.

Comment: @user2162278 Notice that the size of `A1` should be `1` and not `2`.